# Change hover colour of button in navbar in MVC bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I took an example theme and changed the navbar to the same colour as the background (so it's invisible but present). Now when I hover over a button glyphicon it disappears because the hover colour is also the same as the background. I know I need to change something in the CSS but I'm not sure how.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="50x50" width="100" height="100" src="data:image/png;base64,..../>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   ---- BELOW IS THE BUTTON I WANT TO CHANGE

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Configuration")" type="button" class="btn navbar-btn"><span style="font-size:2em;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
            </form>

            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the colour of the button when you hover it?

Comment: Yes sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: You can use :hover selector in css for that. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: I got that far but I can't figure out how to apply that to my actual button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :hover selector is used to select elements when you hover over it.

Example:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Can it not be specific to my <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">  ?

Comment: Use it this way .navbar-left:hover {}

Answer (score 0):

I think the default color which is mentioned in the below bootstrap class

```
.btn:hover
{

}
```

is same as the background which you changed for your nav bar. If you want to get some other color for hover you can change color in the above mentioned code of bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css files.